# Receive data from BLE 4.0 with Xabre

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

Currently I have this fairly simple Arduino project that does the following:

```
if (BTSerial.available())
{
  c = BTSerial.read();
  Serial.print(c);

if (c == 1) {
  digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);
  delay(100);
  BTSerial.write("Hello");
}
```

The code above returns a string once it receives a byte from a connected device.
I have tested this with LightBlue Explorer and confirmed that it works!

However, that is not the case with my Xamarin application that I intend to make myself. 
Currently, I have written the following code:

```
public UtilityPage()
{
        Scan_Page();
        InitializeComponent();

        //Method for updating characteristic   
        MyDevice.characteristic.ValueUpdated += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var text_returned = e.Characteristic.Value;
        };
}

//Push page on top of this in order to connect to pheripheral 
async void Scan_Page()
{
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());
}
```

What is happening above, is that I push a modal on top of my `UtilityPage` which contains a `listview` with devices to connect to. Once a device is connected, the modal is popped.

When I press a button on my phone (code left out) it should send a byte string, and vise-versa receive one from the Arduino. It sends the byte string but doesn't receive one, which means that the major problem is `MyDevice.characteristic.ValueUpdated` which apparently isn't listening for any notifications from the connected peripheral.

The Xamarin plugin I'm using is called [Xabre](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le)

Comment: Serial over Bluetooth is not the same as BLE GATT. They are not compatible with each other.

Comment: But I'm still able to get the value from the characteristic though?

Comment: What does it look like in LightBlue?

Comment: Everytime i send a string from the BLE device to the client, i get a notification in LightBlue with a hex string corresponding to what i have written.

Comment: I think, the reason as to why it IS possible to send data serially, is because the HM-10 module has its own microcontroller (CC2541) that takes care of the communication with the actual bluetooth module. (just a thought)